# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.media.ThumbnailUtils

Tags: java, android

i try to use the [`android.media.ThumbnailUtils`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.html) class to fetch the video thumbnails from  the video which is locate under specified path, for that i use the following code,

```
Bitmap thumb = android.media.ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail("/sdcard/video/sample.mp4",
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
return thumb;
```

but it generates this exception.
        `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.media.ThumbnailUtils`

Anyone suggest some idea to solve this.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not positive, but I think this will come up when you don't have an API level specified on your project, and deploy the app (emulator or device) and you're using an API level higher than what is available.  That class is available for API level 8.  Make sure that your emulator or device are at least that level.  Otherwise, I'm not sure.  API Level 8 is Android 2.2 if you're not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NoClassDefFoundError makes me think that you're not targeting the right API level.  [ThumbnailUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.html) is only in the SDK as of API level 8 (2.2).  Are you running against Froyo or later?

Answer (score 1):

I have stumbled java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError while using a class from a jar in my project.
I tried many things and solve this by the following steps:
right click on project > properties > Java Build Path > source > add folder > choose /lib (if your jar is in there ofcourse)

Hope this saves a day for you..

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you get a [NoClassDefFoundError](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html), the virtual machine couldn't load the class you asked it to. In most cases, this is due to a classpath problem.

If you're using the Android ADT plugin with Eclipse, much of the classpath work is done for you via the build path. You can check your build path by right-clicking on your project, navigating to Properties>Java Build Path. See if there is a library or project missing there.

Comment: Everything seem fine in build path.. I started a bounty, because I have the same issue and need to see it fixed.

Comment: Could you post the code that seems to be causing the problem?

Comment: ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail("android.resource://com.me.MyApp/" + R.raw.myvideo,MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND)

Tha path is good because that work pretty well:      videoHolder.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://com.me.MyApp/" + R.raw.myvideo));

Comment: @Profete162 the issue here is the NoClassDefFoundError. If this is the error then the solution is straight forward as described in the previous answer. But if you are unable to generate a thumbnail from your video which is under the resources then this needs to be told explicitly. So whats the issue you face??

Comment: Just restarted Eclipse and everything is fine now... Very strange bug, thank a lot.